# Better way of using services in Angular

Tags: angular

I have an `DatesService` which responsible for manipulate dates. Also I have two services who need to use date manipulation - `EventsService` and `CalendarService`. `CalendarService` use `EventsService`.

My question is: what is better (performance and everything else) - include `DatesService` in both services, or in `CalendarService` call `DatesService` through `EventsService` in this way: `this.eventsService.datesService`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We faced a similar "problem" and we decided to create a central **provider service** that contains many other services that are frequently used.

It does not make a difference performance-wise, but it is more convenient to inject only one service instead of several. It keeps the code clean and refactoring is easier.